# Capture Frame Not Video AForge C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, aforge

I have the following code, which captures video and updates a jpg very fast.

What I need is to change this to **capture one frame every x seconds**, so that I can do other stuff to it, like decoding a bar code:

```
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

namespace BAMSystem
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int FrameRate { get; set; }

    private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inputDevices.Items.Clear();

        VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        foreach (FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in VideoCaptureDevices)
        {
            inputDevices.Items.Add(VideoCaptureDevice.Name);
        }
        inputDevices.SelectedIndex = 0;

        FinalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[inputDevices.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);

    }

    public void Start_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                FinalVideo.Start();
    }

    void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
                Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                video.Save("C:\\Users\\Wayneio\\Desktop\\image\\live.jpg");
    }
    public void Stop_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FinalVideo.IsRunning)
        {
            FinalVideo.SignalToStop();
            FinalVideo.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First set the videoCaptureDevice.desiredFrameRate to 1. This should make the NewFrameEventHandler to run once every second.
Then have the NewFrameEventHandler do something after num. of seconds (skips or frames) you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case your camera won't support to set the frame rate. You might use a global variable and only execute if that value = true, which you can do by a simple timer event in Visual Studio.

```
void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
   { if(mytimedevent) {
                    Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                    video.Save("C:\\Users\\Wayneio\\Desktop\\image\\live.jpg");
                    }
     mytimedevent!=mytimedevent  // or set it simply to false.
    }
```

You might also change the value of mytimedevent based on your other calculation: if that's finished, enable it to true, and while it runs, set it to false.